# Connect to OSX shared DVD from Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, network-shares

I can see DVD shared drive in Ubuntu

```
$> avahi-browse -alrt
...
= eth0 IPv4 MacMini                               DVD or CD Sharing    local
   hostname = [MacMini.local]
   address = [192.168.1.2]
   port = [49152]
   txt = ["sys=waMA=01:23:45:67:89:AB,adVF=0x4,adDT=0x7,adCC=0"]
...
```

Is there any way to connect to that drive from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a working client implementation for Linux, but there is a server for the protocol written in Javascript: https://github.com/nightwend/ODSServer/blob/master/ODSServer.js

Based on their implementation, you might be able to talk with the server by sending first a `HEAD` request on that port to an URL corresponding to the disk identifier on the Mac (e.g. `/dev/disk2s0`), with the user agent `CCURLBS::statImage`. You might then be able to read ranges from the CD/DVD by sending `GET` requests with [HTTP Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) in bytes to the Mac, with the right user agent (`CCURLBS::readDataFork`).

A simple way to get what you want would be to script the above to get the full CD/DVD from the server, then simply mount that file as a disk image on the Linux host. This is all assuming that the ODSServer implementation matches the actual Mac's.

Comment: This isn't quite what I had in mind.  I would like to write backup data to the remote Mac CD/DVD drive from Ubuntu Linux.  That includes having control over the device for writing to a disc in the drive as if it were local.